# compiz CCSM crashed launcher- and windows-bar on Ubuntu 14LTS?

Tags: unity, compiz

Wanted to make some window-behavior settings regarding `Alt+Tab`-cycling. Then after wanted to set the default behavior back. Then the entire desktop lost the unity launcher and all window-menu bars. After restart nothing changed.

If I login with an alternative user, unity seems to work fine.

Tried some solution proposals like [Compiz crashes using Ubuntu Classic and Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43244/how-do-i-recover-when-compiz-crashes) and then - after failing - I've reinstalled:

`sudo apt-get remove compiz` (no changes)

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

`sudo apt-get install unity` (no changes)

`sudo install compiz` (no changes)

If `sudo metacity --replace` is used. Following error returns:

`Window manager error: Unable to open X display`

Any suggestions?

---

FYI - I'm not a proficient user - the uninstall/reinstalls were suggested in different forums.

Answer (score 2):

You've probably moved on. But since this comes up in a search, this worked for me:

```
rm -rf ~/.config/compiz-1/*
```

Might want to back up first.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I've moved away towards Debian. So I cannot confirm your answer. I've uprated it anyway.